Elementor : display only one category in loop grid
I'm having some issues with the loop grid in Elementor. I have two categories on my website and created two loop grids. I want to display only one category in each loop grid so I used some CSS to my loop template :
.category-itineraires {
display: none!important;
}

It works well when the loop grids are not one the same page. But when I want to display them on the same page there is a conflict and both of them are not displayed.
Is there any other way to display only one category on a loop without creating this conflict ?
Thanks for your help !

You'll need to ask Elementor's support team about this. Third-party plugins are off topic here.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
